# Can I play a song all the way through?

Tags: sequence

Sequence's battles are fun enough, but sometimes I like the mindless fun of pressing arrow keys in rhythm to the music without the focus of switching boards etc. I noticed the "Mana" board has the same arrow pattern going on each time, and is the same as the board you use to unlock spells.

Is there any way, once I've already unlocked a spell, to play a song all the way through with just one chart and no enemy to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can play songs in practice mode (same thing you get when practicing a scroll before learning it) with the song's full pattern via the bonus menu.

From the main menu, select "bonus". In this menu, you can listen to all the songs you've unlocked so far. If a song has an arrow pattern, there will be an up arrow button between the next/previous buttons. Clicking that (or hitting 1) starts the song in practice mode.

Comment: Tell me if my answer doesn't help because I've already played through the main story line. No idea if the bonus option is available before that, or if you have to unlock the songs beforehand. (There should be 27 tracks in there.)

Comment: I think arrow tracks are unlocked as you proceed through the game

Comment: I only have 9 tracks available right now, so it looks like badp is right.